# Convert SVG Animation to webm or mov

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, video, webm

I am looking for a reliable and easy to execute method of **converting pure SVG Animation into a video format**, preferably **webm** or **mov**. 
The animation in question can be found here - it is my personal work and the result of learning how to handle SVG:

https://jsfiddle.net/473btp7e/

To my surprise my initial searches only yielded incomplete answers with often varying results. Upon further research I found [this](https://bl.ocks.org/veltman/ff864215009174bc5d164ec3533125c2) blog post which creates a `webm` of an SVG animation using [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder).

Is there a way of applying said script to my animation so that I get a `webm` as the result.

Comment: That is not really an animation in the sense that it would run on its own. Look at function `drawFrame()`: It simply draws an new frame after the recording of the last is complete.

Answer (score 5):

If you look closely at the code in that example, you'll see that the video is created by drawing each frame, one by one, onto a `canvas` which is connected to a `MediaRecorder`.

So you'll need to do the same: Pause the animation for each frame, draw that frame onto a `canvas`, move the animation a little for the next frame, and repeat.

There is code for drawing an SVG onto a canvas in the linked example, so the tricky part is to pause the animation at any given time to make a frame, since your animation is all CSS. You can do that by pausing the animation (`animation-play-state: paused`) and adjusting the `animation-delay`. Here is an example of that by itself:

https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/zjXqej?editors=1010

So you can do something similar in your code:

```
//Loop through all animated elements, and update their animation-delay.
//Together with "animation-play-state: paused", this freezes the animation at the specified time.
function freeze(time) {
    animed.forEach(x => {
        const css = x.style;

        if(!x.__originalDelay) {
            const delay = css.animationDelay;
            x.__originalDelay = delay.match(/\d/) ? delay : '0s';
        }

        css.animationPlayState = 'paused';
        css.animationDelay = `calc(${x.__originalDelay} - ${time}ms)`;
    });
}
```

Updated demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/473btp7e/2/

**Update:** Better Firefox support, and the ability to control each frame manually with [`requestFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack#Methods)

https://jsfiddle.net/473btp7e/82/

Comment: This looks useful. It's hard to see the quality of the video in the demo. Is it OK in that it's not jerky or missing frames?

Comment: @PhilvanKleur - The video is captured in real-time, so if you can update the canvas fast enough, everything will be fine. If not, you'll get missing frames or a slowed down video, depending on your settings.